# UWP - AmbiguousMatchException thrown when binding TextBlock.Text property to the property which exists in both base and derived class

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a property in same name in both base and derived class with different data type. When binding the property to TextBlock.Text property, exception occurs while binding itself.

NOTE: Exception is throwing only in UWP. But works fine in WPF.

Exception Screenshots:

ambiguousmatchexception.png

BindingCode:

```
 MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);

Binding myBinding = new Binding();

myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

myBinding.ConverterParameter = null;

myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Default;

myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("MyDataProperty");

myBinding.Source = myDataObject; 

myBinding.ElementName = myDataObject.MyDataProperty; 

textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Model:

```
    public class data
{
    public int MyDataProperty { get; set; }
}


public class MyData : data
{
    private string myDataProperty;

    enter code here
    public MyData() { }


    public MyData(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        myDataProperty = "Last bound time was " + dateTime.ToLongTimeString();
    }


    public new String MyDataProperty
    {
        get { return myDataProperty; }
        set
        {
            myDataProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyDataProperty");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `myBinding.ElementName` ? You are binding to a class, not to an element. Try removing this

Comment: It makes no sense to set both the `Source` property and the `ElementName` property.